# What is default behavior of printing carriage returns in Unix?

Tags: unix, terminal

I see a lot of questions about how to remove them, but I haven't found an answer as to why they "mess up" all my testing/printing functions in Unix systems and terminals.

So, in a programmer sense, why do carriage returns mess up Unix shells.

Edit: Yes I can. I don't mean to rant, but I'm wondering what causes carriage returns to print funny.

An example is getting messages from a system that ends all messages with `\r\n`. Then I have to do something like `message[length - 2] = '\0';` in C or `$str =~ s/\r//g` in perl.

Edit 2: What is the default behavior of printing carriage returns in Unix system? It seems to cause problems and generally needs to be removed.

Comment: Can you supply a concrete example with the code you're using to "fix" it?  And ask a question about that code?  This seems like more of a rant than a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they're unnecessary and unwelcome on Unix systems.

You should take a look at your `stty` settings too.  There are options to handle NL/CR mapping on input and output.  On a Linux box, `stty -a` said:

```
speed 9600 baud; rows 65; columns 120; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^X; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q;
stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts -cdtrdsr
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Note `-ocrnl`, `onlcr`, `-onocr`, `-onlret`, `-inlcr`, `-igncr`, `-icrnl` in particular.

Be careful about messing with them.  You can experiment with them if you preserve your current sane terminal settings:

```
saved_tty_settings=$(stty -g)

...tinker with the settings here...

stty $saved_tty_settings
```

One problem could be that you fix things so that return no longer sends to the terminal.  In that case, try typing <kbd>Control-J</kbd>`stty $saved_tty_settings`<kbd>Control-J</kbd>.  The first control-J flushes whatever command was there previously (or does nothing); then the rest runs the `stty` reset operation.  I still have a script called `sane` that has a record of my preferred tty settings that I can use if I have to.  I haven't used it often in the last decade or so, but I haven't gone fiddling with tty settings either.

Do be extremely cautious about using dangerous commands (`rm` et al) and even using quotes can lead to problem (if you can't see what you've typed and you lose track and you've disabled line editing, etc).  So, you can play; just be careful.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the different systems interpreting different character combinations to denote end-of-line. Windows uses `\r\n`, *unix used `\n` and Mac at one point used `\r`. Now when you get Windows created text file in Unx you get extra `\r` before `\n` and that needs to be removed.

There is a nice utility called [dos2unix](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_dos2uni.htm) that handles this format conversion for you.